# python telegram bot ForceReply callback

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm currently developing a telegram bot with python-telegram-bot. I want to be able to get the message, that was replied to ForceReply. The expected flow is this:

1. User sends /start command
2. Bot sends a message with some information. The message is linked with ForceReply
3. User replies to the message
4. Handle and operate the message.

How could I achieve the expected result? Thanks

```
initial_message = "Hi... Please reply to this message to proceed to the next step..."

def start (update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    print(update.message.from_user.username)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=initial_message, reply_markup=ForceReply())
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to handle the `ForceReply()` you must implement a `ConversationHandler`. Once the user reply to `ForceReply`, with the `ConversationHandler`, you'll be able to deal with his/her reply. That's how it's done:

```
END = ConversationHandler.END
NEXTSTEP = range (1)

initial_message = "Hi... Please reply to this message to proceed to the next step..."
def start (update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    print(update.message.from_user.username)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id,
                             text=initial_message,
                             reply_markup=ForceReply())

    return NEXTSTEP

def nextstep (update, context):

    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    ##user reply will be assigned to replied variable below
    replied = update.message.text
    print(replied)

    return END

def main():
    ##handler start
    start_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points = [CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states = {
            NEXTSTEP: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, nextstep)]},
        fallbacks = [CommandHandler('cancel', callback = functions.cancel)])
    dp.add_handler(start_handler)
```

Comment: Good example, works well