# How to handle replies in with Pyrogram when using ForceReply?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, pyrogram

I am building a telegram bot where I am attempting to get the user to fill in detail about an event and store them in a dictionary which is itself in a list.

However I want it be link a conversation. I want it to look like:

user: /create

bot-reply: What would you like to call it?

user-reply: Chris' birth day

bot-reply: When is it?

user-reply: 08/11/2021

bot-reply: Event Chris birth day on 08/11/2021 has been saved!

To achieve this I plan to use [ForceReply](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/ForceReply?highlight=forcereply#pyrogram.types.ForceReply) which states in the documentation

> This can be extremely useful if you want to create user-friendly step-by-step interfaces without having to sacrifice privacy mode.

The problem is the documentation does not seem to explain how to handle responses.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
@app.on_message(filters.command('create'))
async def create_countdown(client, message):
    global countdowns
    countdown = {
        'countdown_id': str(uuid4())[:8],
        'countdown_owner_id': message.from_user.id,
        'countdown_onwner_username': message.from_user.username,
        }
    try:
        await message.reply('What do you want to name the countdown?', 
                            reply_markup=ForceReply()
        )

    except FloodWait as e:
        await asyncio.sleep(e.x)
```

Looking through the form I have found options like this:
[python telegram bot ForceReply callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294257/python-telegram-bot-forcereply-callback)
which are exactly what I am looking for but they are using different libraries like python-telegram-bot which permit them to use ConversationHandler. It seems to not be part of pyrogram

How to I **create user-friendly step-by-step interfaces** with pyrogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyrogram doesn't have a ConversationHandler.

You could use a `dict` with your users' ID as the key and the state they're in as the value, then you can use that dictionary of states as your reference to know where your User is in the conversation.

> Dan: (Pyrogram creator)
> A conversation-like feature is not available yet in the lib. One way to do that is saving states into a dictionary using user IDs as keys. Check the dictionary before taking actions so that you know in which step your users are and update it once they successfully go past one action
> https://t.me/pyrogramchat/213488